# email sending code shows an error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is email sendind code

```
function send_letter()

    {

        $description =  $this->input->post('description',true);

        $this->load->model('newsletter_model');

        $this->data['mail_list'] = $this->newsletter_model->getmaillist();

        $this->email->from('ashitha10@gmail.com', 'Imageinit');

        $this->email->subject('Email Test');

        $this->email->message($description);

        foreach($this->data['mail_list'] as $val)

        {

            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

            $this->email->to($val['emailid']);

            $this->email->send();

        }  


        $this->index();

    }
```

The email sends successfully to all emailids..But subject like "nosubject"

Also an error shows

> Security:Notice
>
> Message:Undefined Index:subject
>
> FileName:libraries/email.php
>
> line Number:941

content in line 941 in **email.php** is

```
if ($this->protocol == 'mail')

        {

            $this->_subject = $this->_headers['Subject'];

            unset($this->_headers['Subject']);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the code which `unset`s the `Subject` header is in the method `_write_headers`, which is called from `_build_message` which is called from `send`. So every time you call `send` with `mail` as backend your subject gets erased (but the first mail is okay, since the subject gets stored in `$this->_subject` but that gets overwritten with an empty string in a subsequent call too).

This seems like a bug in the email.php, but as a workaround you could just set the subject in every iteration of the loop (so just move `$this->email->subject('Email Test');` inside of the `foreach`-loop, maybe after the `to`-call).

Comment: ya..i put $this->email->subject('Email Test'); inside the loop.Now it is ok..thank u.....

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

function send_letter()

```
{

    $description =  $this->input->post('description',true);

    $this->load->model('newsletter_model');

    $this->data['mail_list'] = $this->newsletter_model->getmaillist();



    foreach($this->data['mail_list'] as $val)

    {

        $this->email->from('ashitha10@gmail.com', 'Imageinit');

        $this->email->subject('Email Test');

        $this->email->message($description);


        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->to($val['emailid']);

        $this->email->send();

    }  


    $this->index();

}
```